# How to copy several specified files from a source folder and its subfolders to a destination folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, robocopy

I have source folder: `c:\prefix\bin`

I want to copy a set of specified files from source folder and its subfolders.

Lets say I want to copy:

```
bin
... gtsam.dll
... msvcr120.dll
... intel64\
    ... vc12\
        ... tbb.dll
```

To be more clearly for what I want to copy:

```
.\gtsam.dll .\msvcr120.dll .\intel64\vc12\tbb.dll
```

There are many files in the source directory and many subdirectories that I don't want to copy. And all the specified files I have to copy do not share a wild card. They are not all `*.dll` to copy to `c:\dst`

How I can do it with the most elegant way?

Using **copy**, or **xcopy**, or **robocopy**?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to create first a simple text file containing line by line the files to copy with relative path.

Example for `FilesList.txt`:

```
gtsam.dll
msvcr120.dll
intel64\vc12\tbb.dll
```

It is up to you in which directory to store this list file with the names of the files to copy.
The code below expects this file in directory `C:\prefix\bin`.

Then create a batch file with following code:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\prefix\bin"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in ("FilesList.txt") do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%~F" C:\dst\ /C /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
)
popd
```

If target is specified with a backslash at end as done here and option `/I` is used, console application **xcopy** expects that `C:\dst` is a directory and even creates the entire directory structure to this directory automatically if not already existing.

Or you use this script with command **copy** and making sure the destination directory exists before copying the files.

```
@echo off
if not exist "C:\dst" (
    md "C:\dst"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo.
        echo Failed to create directory C:\dst
        echo.
        pause
        goto :EOF
    )
)
pushd "C:\prefix\bin"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in ("FilesList.txt") do (
    copy /B /Y "%%~F" C:\dst\ >nul
)
popd
```

Command **md** creates also entire directory tree on creating a directory with command extensions enabled as by default.

In both cases the directory `C:\dst` contains after batch file execution:

- gtsam.dll
- msvcr120.dll
- tbb.dll

The main advantage of using a list file containing the names of the files to copy with relative path is easy updating in future without the need to change the batch code.

But let's say the files should be copied with duplicating the directory structure from source to destination directory resulting in directory `C:\dst` containing after batch file execution:

- gtsam.dll
- msvcr120.dll
- **intel64**

  - **vc12**

    - tbb.dll

In this case the batch code with **xcopy** could be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "C:\prefix\bin"
if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" ( set "BasePath=%CD%" ) else ( set "BasePath=%CD%\" )

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in ("FilesList.txt") do (
    set "SourcePath=%%~dpF"
    set "RelativePath=!SourcePath:%BasePath%=!"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%~F" "C:\dst\!RelativePath!" /C /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
)

popd
endlocal
```

And the batch code using **copy** could be:

```
@echo off
if not exist "C:\dst" (
    md "C:\dst"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo.
        echo Failed to create directory C:\dst
        echo.
        pause
        goto :EOF
    )
)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "C:\prefix\bin"
if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" ( set "BasePath=%CD%" ) else ( set "BasePath=%CD%\" )

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in ("FilesList.txt") do (
    set "SourcePath=%%~dpF"
    set "RelativePath=!SourcePath:%BasePath%=!"
    md "C:\dst\!RelativePath!" 2>nul
    copy /B /Y "%%~F" "C:\dst\!RelativePath!" >nul
)

popd
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `md /?`
- `pause /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

Comment: `even creates the entire directory structure to this directory automatically if not already existing.` that is not correct. When you create the sample textfile with the file list and the batch as described, then the files are getting copied to the destionation directories root (the destionation is getting creating if it does not exist) but the directory structure, if it does not exist on the destination) is not created automatically.

Comment: @STORM The first batch code creates the directory `dst` in root of drive C: automatically if not already existing which is what I wrote. It is not really clear what the OP wanted for file `intel64\vc12\tbb.dll`. Should this file be copied to `C:\dst\tbb.dll` as I understood from the question or to `C:\dst\intel64\vc12\tbb.dll` as you obviously think. I added the code examples for second variant and added destination folder output examples for all 4 batch codes which the OP should have already given to make it clear what is really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
@echo off

set "basedir=c:\prefix\bin"
set "destination=c:\destination"

for /r "%basedir%" %%# in (*gtsam.dll *msvcr120.dll *tbb.dll) do (
  copy "%%~f#" "%destination%"
)
```